# Question about ramified morphism from smooth variety to projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f:X\rightarrow P^n$ be a $d:1$ ramified covering over the complex $\mathbb{C}$. Here $X$ is smooth projective variety. I have some questions.

a) what is direct image of structure sheaf $f_*O_X$. It will be rank $d$ locally free. But will it split as direct sum of line bundles. What will be the line bundles ?

b) if $d=2$, then there is inverse map $i$ on $X$ which interchanges the elements from the decks. Then I saw somewhere that $i$ acts on sheaf as well and it splits into $\pm$ eigen spaces. Can someone tell me what this action is exactly? I can only see action on global sections.

Also for $d>2$ will $S_d$ act on $X$ hence the structure sheaf? Set of fixed points of action is ramification divisor $R$ correct?

c) if $B=f(R)$ base divisor. Suppose $B$ smooth irreducible. Is $f^*B=dR$? Let $D$ be any smooth divisor in $P^n$, what is $f^*D$? When will this be reduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) $f_*(\mathcal{O}_X)$ will in general, not split as direct sum of line bundles. For an example, take an abelian surface $X$ for some suitable $d$. If the direct image splits as sum of line bundles, it will force $H^1(\mathcal{O}_X)=0$, which is not true for an abelian surface.

b) $d=2$ case is the only one which can be understood well. One has the exact sequence in all cases $0\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\to f_*(\mathcal{O}_X)\to E\to 0$ (define $E$ by this) and this splits by the trace map. So, if $d=2$, one has $E$ a line bundle. Now, studying the algebra structure on $f_*(\mathcal{O}_X)=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}\oplus E$ where $E=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-r)$, you should see how the action works.

c) Not much can be said in this generality. In particular, it is rare when $f^*B=dR$.

Comment: if $X$ is the projective space, can we   something about $f_*O_X$?

Comment: I did not understand your part (c). Do you mean that $f^*B=dR$ happens rarely? If divisor is not the branch divisor we could form fiber product to get divisor in $X$. Will this be reduced?

Comment: If $X$ is the projective space, then yes, the direct image will be a direct sum of line bundles, by Horrock's criterion.

Comment: thank you, what about part (c)